# Why doesn't a message appear when sending an email? - smtplib - Python

Tags: python, smtp

For some reason when trying to send an email no message appears, when I pass the string *msg*

**Here's the code I'm using:**

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("my_email", "my_password")

msg = "my message"
server.sendmail("eggs@eggs.com", "eggs_2@eggs.com", msg)
server.quit()
```

*Any alternative methods or solutions would be great.*

***Edit:***

*When I send the e-mail(to myself) no message appears just an empty e-mail appears in my inbox. Is there an alternative 'built-in' library that I can use?*

Comment: Have you approved this login from gmail. As a security feature Gmail emails om "my_email" for approval.

Comment: No message appears where? Do you mean "the message is not sent"?

Comment: Terribly sorry I didn't clarify that. Going to edit it.

Comment: Never mind. The reason was you need to add a \n to your message. This separates it from the header and then Python can format it correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to my above question is:

The variable *my_message* just needs *\n*before the text to separate it from the header.